# How to mock specific methods but not all of them in Rust?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, mocking

I have troubles figuring out unit tests for the methods of the target struct.

I have a method `random_number` that returns a random value based on the attribute of the struct and there is another method `plus_one` that takes the result of the first method and does something with it:

```
pub struct RngTest {
    pub attr: u64,
}

impl RngTest {
    pub fn random_number(&self) -> u64 {
        let random = 42; // lets pretend it is random
        return random * self.attr;
    }

    pub fn plus_one(&self) -> u64 {
        return self.random_number() + 1;
    }
}
```

Having a unit test for the first method, what is the strategy to test the other? I want to mock `self.random_number()` output for the unit test of `plus_one()` to have sane code in unit tests. There is a nice post that compares [different mocking libraries](https://asomers.github.io/mock_shootout/) and concludes (sadly enough) that none of them is really good to stand out from the others.

The only thing I learned while reading instructions for these libraries is that the only way I can mock methods is by moving them to a trait. I didn't see any example in these libraries (I looked at 4 or 5 of them) where they test a case similar to this.

After moving these methods to a trait (even as they are), how do I mock `random_number` to unit test the output of `RngTest::plus_one`?

```
pub trait SomeRng {
    fn random_number(&self) -> u64 {
        let random = 42; // lets pretend it is random
        return random * self.attr;
    }

    fn plus_one(&self) -> u64 {
        return self.random_number() + 1;
    }
}

impl SomeRng for RngTest {}
```

Comment: Don't make sense in Rust ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to mock specific methods but not all of them in Rust?

As you have already learned, you cannot replace methods on a type. The only thing you can do is move the methods to a trait and then provide production and test-specific implementations of that trait. How you structure the trait determines the granularity of what you are able to test.

## Trait with a default implementation

Depending on your use case, you might be able to use a default implementation:

```
trait SomeRng {
    fn random_number(&self) -> u64;

    fn plus_one(&self) -> u64 {
        self.random_number() + 1
    }
}

struct RngTest(u64);
impl SomeRng for RngTest {
    fn random_number(&self) -> u64 {
        self.0
    }
}

#[test]
fn plus_one_works() {
    let rng = RngTest(41);
    assert_eq!(rng.plus_one(), 42);
}
```

Here, `random_number` is a required method, but `plus_one` has a default implementation. Implementing `random_number` gives you `plus_one` by default. You could also choose to implement `plus_one` if you could do it more efficiently.

## What does the real rand crate do?

The real [rand crate](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5) uses two traits:

- [`Rng`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/trait.Rng.html)

  ```
  pub trait Rng: RngCore { /* ... */ }
  ```

  > An automatically-implemented extension trait on `RngCore` providing high-level generic methods for sampling values and other convenience methods.
- [`RngCore`](https://docs.rs/rand/0.6.5/rand/trait.RngCore.html)

  ```
  pub trait RngCore { /* ... */ }
  ```

  > The core of a random number generator.

This splits the core interesting parts of the implementation from the helper methods. You can then control the core and test the helpers:

```
trait SomeRngCore {
    fn random_number(&self) -> u64;
}

trait SomeRng: SomeRngCore {
    fn plus_one(&self) -> u64 {
        self.random_number() + 1
    }
}

impl<R: SomeRngCore> SomeRng for R {}

struct RngTest(u64);
impl SomeRngCore for RngTest {
    fn random_number(&self) -> u64 {
        self.0
    }
}

#[test]
fn plus_one_works() {
    let rng = RngTest(41);
    assert_eq!(rng.plus_one(), 42);
}
```

Comment: Does ` impl<R: SomeRngCore> SomeRng for R {} ` mean every Struct impl SomeRngCore  will have SomeRng's methods too ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining a *stub* as Shepmaster done in their answer, you can use the crate `mockall` to define a real *mock* (more flexible). You still have to follow the struct + trait pattern as Shepmaster proposed:

```rs
pub struct RngTest {
    pub attr: u64,
}

trait SomeRng {
    fn random_number(&self) -> u64;

    fn plus_one(&self) -> u64 {
        self.random_number() + 1
    }
}

// Your real implementation
impl SomeRng for RngTest {
    fn random_number(&self) -> u64 {
        42
    }
}


// Test part

mock! {
    SomeRngForTest {}
    impl SomeRng for SomeRngForTest {
        fn random_number(&self) -> u64;
    }
}


mod rngtest {
    use super::{SomeRng, MockSomeRngForTest};

    #[test]
    fn test() {
        let mut mock = MockSomeRngForTest::new();
        mock.expect_random_number().return_const(100u64);

        assert_eq!(mock.plus_one(), 101);
    }
}
```

See: https://docs.rs/mockall/latest/mockall/

Comment: I get "no `MockSomeRngForTest`" with this. I assume that your `mock!` block is meant to be outside the `mod test` (`mod rngtest`) block. But in fact I get "no `MockSomeRngForTest`" in either case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Shepmaster I came to this workaround. I have added the actual `Rng` to have more context.

```
use rand::{thread_rng, Rng}; // 0.6.5

struct RngTest(Vec<u64>);

impl RngTest {
    fn random_number(&self) -> u64 {
        let random_value = thread_rng().choose(&self.0);
        *random_value.unwrap()
    }

    fn plus_one(&self) -> u64 {
        self.random_number() + 1
    }
}

#[test]
fn plus_one_works() {
    let rng = RngTest(vec![1]);
    assert_eq!(rng.plus_one(), 2);
}
```

I can set an appropriate value in the object and don't need to use traits. There is a downside though - this forces me to have a special instance of my type for this specific test which I would like to avoid because my actual type has *a lot* of fields and I wanted to define its creation once for all the tests using `speculate`.